# ArcCatalog Registering a Feature Class into Geodatabase: Getting an Error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-database, attachments

This is a SQL Server GeoDatabase. I have created a couple of tables using SSMS; then imported data to them. Then, inside ArcMAP, I created Layers and pointed their data to these tables via SDE. So now I have an MXD with Feature Classes.Then I defined Relationships between the Feature Classes.

So far so good. What I now need is to enable Attachments on a couple of these Feature Classes. I suppose I can't do that until I Register these Feature Classes into the GeoDatabase using ArcCatalog because the Enable Attachment option is not available?

Assuming that was the problem, I tried to do the 'Register with GeoDatabase' from ArcCatalog but am getting an error: 'Invalid Entity Type'? I have Googled but can't find anything which would help me. This is just a local test environment but I need to learn enough from it to implement an enterprise wide setup.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I think I am getting the 'Invalid Entity Type' error because some Geometry data in my Feature Classes is invalid. The following page gave me the clue:

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2290&t=283546

So I deleted all rows from the Feature Classes and, voila, the error went away and I was asked to specify Geometry--which I did. And now I am able to Enable Attachments.